# What does AES 256 error means Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?

Tags: encryption, aes

Firstly I've seen few issues raised on "Padding is invalid and can not be removed". I looked all of them and my issue is quiet different.

I am using a code below  where I can encrypt the data from PS script and decrypt from .NET application.

However, when I try to encrypt the text on .NET/PS script and try to decrypt on site below it doesn't work.

https://aesencryption.net/

When I try to decrypted the encrypted data from this site on to PS or .NET code (using same key) I keep getting this error:
***"Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."***

I used 256 bit key and key is exactly same.

```
/// <summary>
    /// AES wrapper implementation by Yovav Gad using the AesManaged algorithm.
    /// <para>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard</para>
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class AesWrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a SymmetricAlgorithm using AesManaged
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Byte array representing the key values, please note, 
        /// for better performance, use Convert.FromBase64String() outside of this method.</param>
        /// <param name="blockSize">BlockSize, default is 128</param>
        /// <param name="paddingMode">PaddingMode, default is PaddingMode.PKCS7</param>
        /// <param name="cipherMode">CipherMode, default is CipherMode.CBC</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static SymmetricAlgorithm CreateCrypto(
            byte[] key,
            int blockSize = 128,
            PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC
            )
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm crypto = new AesManaged
            {
                Key = key,
                Mode = cipherMode,
                Padding = paddingMode,
                BlockSize = blockSize
            };

            crypto.IV = new byte[crypto.IV.Length];

            return (crypto);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt an encrypted string using a specific key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str">String to decrypt</param>
        /// <param name="key">Byte array representing the key values, please note, 
        /// for better performance, use Convert.FromBase64String() outside of this method.</param>
        /// <param name="blockSize">BlockSize, default is 128</param>
        /// <param name="paddingMode">PaddingMode, default is PaddingMode.Zeros</param>
        /// <param name="cipherMode">CipherMode, default is CipherMode.CBC</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DebuggerStepThrough()]
        public static string Decrypt(
            string str,
            byte[] key,
            int blockSize = 128,
            PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC
            )
        {
            if (str == null || str.Length < 1 ||
                key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var result = string.Empty;

            using (var crypto = CreateCrypto(key, blockSize, paddingMode, cipherMode))
            {
                var strCombined = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
                var iv = new byte[crypto.BlockSize / 8];
                var cipherText = new byte[strCombined.Length - iv.Length];
                Array.Copy(strCombined, iv, iv.Length);
                Array.Copy(strCombined, iv.Length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

                crypto.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = crypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

                using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (paddingMode == PaddingMode.PKCS7)
                {
                    // This is required when using PaddingMode.Zeros for values shorted than the block size.
                    // Note: using .TrimEnd('\0') to remove nulls and not .TrimEnd("\0") to allow the string values.
                    result = result.TrimEnd('\0');
                }

                return (result);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt a string using a specific key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str">String to encrypt</param>
        /// <param name="key">Byte array representing the key values, please note, 
        /// for better performance, use Convert.FromBase64String() outside of this method.</param>
        /// <param name="blockSize">BlockSize, default is 128</param>
        /// <param name="paddingMode">PaddingMode, default is PaddingMode.Zeros</param>
        /// <param name="cipherMode">CipherMode, default is CipherMode.CBC</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DebuggerStepThrough()]
        public static string Encrypt(
            string str,
            byte[] key,
            int blockSize = 128,
            PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC
            )
        {
            if (str == null || str.Length < 1 ||
                key == null || key.Length < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] encryptedData;

            using (SymmetricAlgorithm crypto = CreateCrypto(key, blockSize, paddingMode, cipherMode))
            {
                byte[] data;
                crypto.GenerateIV();
                var iv = crypto.IV;
                var encryptor = crypto.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        {
                            sw.Write(str);
                        }

                        data = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }

                // Combine the iv (salt) and the encrypted data
                encryptedData = new byte[iv.Length + data.Length];
                Array.Copy(iv, 0, encryptedData, 0, iv.Length);
                Array.Copy(data, 0, encryptedData, iv.Length, data.Length);
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
    }


void Main()
{
    var keyString = "8CBaNtMYwAuu2K/xleoRfgPkURaLK82QidlIyg+nFY4=";
    var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString); 
    var plainText = "aes test";
    
    var testEncrypted = AesWrapper.Encrypt(plainText, keyBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(testEncrypted);
    var testDecrypted = AesWrapper.Decrypt("gM+oae1MZlj42b9UtCw2dw==", keyBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(testDecrypted);
    var testReEncrypted = AesWrapper.Encrypt(testEncrypted, keyBytes);
}
```

PS Script

```
    function Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    if ($IV) {
        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.IV = $IV
        }
    }
    if ($key) {
        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.Key = $key
        }
    }
    $aesManaged
}

function Create-AesKey() {
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject
    $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.Key)
}

function Encrypt-String($key, $unencryptedString) {
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($unencryptedString)
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key
    $encryptor = $aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()
    $encryptedData = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    [byte[]] $fullData = $aesManaged.IV + $encryptedData
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fullData)
}

function Decrypt-String($key, $encryptedStringWithIV) {
    $bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encryptedStringWithIV)
    $IV = $bytes[0..15]
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key $IV
    $decryptor = $aesManaged.CreateDecryptor();
    $unencryptedData = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 16, $bytes.Length - 16);
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($unencryptedData).Trim([char]0)
}


cls

<#
# This will generate a new valid AES 256 key if needed:
# $key = Create-AesKey
#>

<# 
# This is the hard coded key
#>
$key = Create-AesKey
#$key = "8CBaNtMYwAuu2K/xleoRfgPkURaLK82Q"
Write-Host "key = $key"

$unencryptedString = "dil pun"
Write-Host "unencryptedString = $unencryptedString"

$encryptedString = Encrypt-String $key $unencryptedString
Write-Host "encryptedString  = $encryptedString "

$backToPlainText = Decrypt-String $key $encryptedString
Write-Host "backToPlainText = $backToPlainText"


<#
# To run this PowerShell script:
#
# In Windows PowerShell:
# .\PowerShell_AES_Encryption_Example.ps1
# C:\Test\PowerShell_AES_Encryption_Example.ps1
# 
# In Command Prompt:
# powershell -noexit "& ""C:\Test\PowerShell_AES_Encryption_Example.ps1"""
#>
```

Any idea why this code can not decrypt the data that's been encrypted by https://aesencryption.net/ using same key and vice versa?

And what exactly does both party need to match ? E.g key size, key value, Padding and mode.

Does IV, based etc needs to match?

Thanks.

Comment: All this work to write a question and the padding mode is *explicitly* different in both snippets.

Comment: In the one code I see `PaddingMode.Zeros` and in the other code padding mode is set to [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) which never uses zeros. You need to use the exact same padding algorithm for decryption and encryption!

Comment: Yes already tried with having both same padding I.e PKS7. Still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> And what exactly does both party need to match

For AES everything you have to use the exact same values for encryption and decryption:

- key (print it as hex key and compare it)
- IV (16 bytes of random data for encryption, and for decryption use the same bytes as used for encryption). The common way is to prepend the IV to the encrypted data and read it before performing the actual decryption.
- Crypto mode (here CBC)
- Padding